# read a json file from webservice in windows phone

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, data-binding

I am very new to Windows Phone applications. I have a JSON file that I get from the following URL.

```
http://www.krcgenk.be/mobile/json/request/news/
```

Now I want the title being showed in a list on my Windows Phone. I have the following XAML for that.

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="News" Height="532">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="0,0,12,0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Now I need to know how I can put the title and description into my list. 
After some Google work I found that I should use JSON.net framework. this gave me following code.

```
var w = new WebClient();

Observable
  .FromEvent<DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs>(w, "DownloadStringCompleted")
  .Subscribe(r =>
  {
      var deserialized =
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<News>>(r.EventArgs.Result);
      PhoneList.ItemsSource = deserialized;
  });
w.DownloadStringAsync(
  new Uri("http://www.krcgenk.be/mobile/json/request/news/"));
```

I also create a news Class with getters and setters.
But when I build and run. I get the following errors.

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into 
type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[KrcGenk.Classes.News]' because the 
type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) 
or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not 
a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or 
List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute 
can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Path 'news', line 1, position 8.
```

Hope anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url returns an object (that is what the error message says). So you're not supposed to deserialize it into a list. The deserialization should look like this:

```
var deserialized =
                JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NewsEntry>(r.EventArgs.Result);
```

NewsEntry should contain a list of news

```
class NewsEntry {
    public List<News> News { get; set; }
    public NewsEntry() {
        News = new List<News>();
    }
}
```

Note: I assumed the News class has all properties. Maybe you need to adjust this one.

Comment: My class calls News. Should I replace NewsEntry by News ?

Comment: You are supposed to create a new class NewsEntry that contains a property called News. The json returned delivers an object (not a list/array) containing a property called news that actually is a list/array of News. So my proposed NewsEntry class delivers the outer container if you like to name it that way.

Comment: Oké I did that, but now it gives me the following errors. Error 1 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.IObserver<Microsoft.Phone.Reactive.IEvent<System.Net.DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs>>' because it is not a delegate type and thisError 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'KrcGenk.Classes.NewsEntry' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Try changing PhoneList.ItemsSource = deserialized; to PhoneList.ItemsSource = deserialized.News; as News contains the list

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this blog post http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.gr/2012/01/json-deserialization-with-jsonnet.html